# Cultivation manhua/webtoon about a leader of a demon sect who dies and is reincarnated into the body of a young boy

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, cultivation

Basically, the main character (MC) was the leader of this demon sect (I think; I can't remember the name correctly) and was dying due to old age. His four disciples (basically three, because one disciple went on a journey for a ginseng that makes you immortal) were waiting for him to return. The disciple that was looking for the ginseng that makes you immortal found it and came back, trying to feed it to the MC. The other disciples TRY to stop the MC from eating the ginseng, although they ultimately fail. The MC was already dead when he ate the ginseng, so his soul was returning to his body.

The reaper that was supposed to take his life realizes this and decides to reincarnate(?) him into the body of a young boy who just fell off a cliff while trying to get a flower that cures diseases for his master, who was ill. He wakes up to see Taoists (if I remember correctly) healing him, which weakens his initial dark energy tremendously (again, if I remember correctly). The specifics of this may be off, but it has been a while since I've read this, and it's about all that I remember. If you do know what manhua/webtoon or whatever it is, please spill!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *Path of the Shaman* by Eunyeol and Hwaram.

> If the Grim Reaper calls your name three times, you will be taken to the underworld.
>
> "Hyeokyeon Mugang."
>
> "Hyeokyeon Mugang."
>
> "Hyeokyeon Mu..."
>
> You little shit! I want to live longer! Get out of here!
>
> **I desperately swallowed the Herb of Immortality**, and to my surprise, I
> actually lived! When I finally opened my eyes, thinking it was all a
> dream... **I was surrounded by a bunch of old guys**?! I asked where am,
> and—the Shamans' Mountain?!!!!!!!!
>
> Somehow,
> **I possessed the body of a pitiful errand boy**
>
> ... this is nuts!
>
> I... I am... I am the strongest of the strong, the head of the Sa
> Clan, Hyeokyeon Mugang!!! Why am I now part of a clan of Shamans?!
>
> Well, since I'm here, I might as well become the best disciple I can.
> The trashy master's ruthless, no-holds-barred, immortal martial arts
> story "Path of the Shaman" begins!

Your description is quite on point, the MC finds himself getting healed by the Taoists after falling from a cliff while looking for medicinal herbs for his master.